# Delete cassandra keyspaces using regular expression

Tags: cassandra, pattern-matching, nosql

I am working on a functionality where one tenant can have multiple keyspaces. If the tenant is removed, all keyspaces related to that tenant should be deleted. Instead of deleting one keyspace at a time, I was thinking that all keyspaces of a tenant have some pattern like tenantid_tenantname_... and if there is some CQL command for deleting keyspace based on matching pattern?

For example: drop keyspace tenantid_tenantname_*